# use whole picture as a border for a div tag

Tags: css, html, user-interface, border

i have a slideshow of pictures with right and left arrows for navigation.this slideshow exists within a div tag.now i have to put this slideshow of pictures in a frame. The frame is picture of a smartphone like shown below:
[Frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtKDm.png)
i want the slideshow of pics to be displayed in the white space inside the phone.i tried using the css style of border-image but all 4 sides have different pictures.help me as i am new to this.
information: slideshow picture size:400 width 250 height.
kindly provide me with code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

put "screen" `div` in another `div` with background phone picture?

```
<div style="background-image:phone.jpg; margin: 30px 20px 30px 20px;">
    <div id="screen">
    </div>
</div>
```